# Binding a plain binary file in to an excecutable

Tags: visual-c++, linker, g++, clang

The following question isn't related to an actual problem but what I just was curious about:
How can I link a whole file with an executable and get the starting address and size of that block at runtime in C / C++ ? Sometimes it would be nice to have a single executable which contains some resorces which conventionally would be external files to be read at runtime.
Any examples related to any compiler system or platform would be appreciated.
Aside from that it would be nice to have standard means in C / C++ to do that.
I intentionally don't post this questions with any tag related to specific languages but just with tags that are related to specific implementations.

Comment: Windows has the concept of [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/introduction-to-resources) that do exactly this. See [`FindResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea) et al.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: And you can include an arbitrary binary into a resource ?

Comment: Yes, indeed you can.

Answer (score 1):

As there was no proper answer I wrote a little C++20-program that converts a file to a C-file with a unsigned char array and a header file with just the declaration of this array.
The first parameter is the file to become the array, the second parameter is the name of the output-files without an extension, the third parameter is the name of the array and there's an optional fourth parameter with the number of bytes per line, which is defaulted to 16.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <charconv>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    try
    {
        if( argc < 4 )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        size_t bytesPerLine = 16;
        char const
            *inFile = argv[1],
            *outFile = argv[2],
            *symbolName = argv[3],
            *sBytesPerLine = argc >= 5 ? argv[4] : nullptr;
        if( sBytesPerLine )
        {
            from_chars_result fcr = from_chars( sBytesPerLine, sBytesPerLine + strlen( argv[3] ), bytesPerLine );
            if( fcr.ec != errc() || *fcr.ptr )
                throw invalid_argument( "number of bytes per line format error" );
        }
        ifstream ifs;
        ifs.exceptions( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit );
        ifs.open( inFile, ifstream::in | ifstream::binary );
        ifs.seekg( 0, ifstream::end );
        streampos spSize = ifs.tellg();
        if( spSize > (size_t)-1 )
            throw invalid_argument( "file too large" );
        size_t size = (size_t)spSize;
        if( !size )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        using vc_t = vector<char>;
        using vc_it = typename vc_t::iterator;
        vc_t data( size, 0 );
        ifs.seekg( 0, ifstream::beg );
        ifs.read( data.data(), (streamsize)size );
        ofstream ofsHeader, ofsC;
        auto writeDelcaration = [&]( ofstream &ofs, bool definition )
        {
            ofs.exceptions( ofstream::failbit | ofstream::badbit );
            ofs.open( string( string( outFile ) + (!definition ? ".h" : ".c") ).c_str(), ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc | ofstream::binary );
            ofs << (!definition ? "extern " : "") << "unsigned char const " << symbolName << "[" << data.size() << "]" << (!definition ? ";" : " = ") << endl;;
        };
        writeDelcaration( ofsHeader, false );
        writeDelcaration( ofsC, true );
        ofsC << "{" << endl;
        string bulk;
        auto writeBulk = [&]<typename AppendFn>( AppendFn appendFn )
            requires requires( AppendFn appendFn, string_view const &sv ) { { appendFn( sv ) }; }
        {
            size_t remaining = data.size(), bytesInLine;
            for( vc_it cIt = data.begin(); remaining; remaining -= bytesInLine )
            {
                bytesInLine = remaining >= bytesPerLine ? bytesPerLine : remaining;
                appendFn( "\t" );
                for( size_t b = 0; b != bytesInLine; ++b )
                {
                    char hex[2 + 2 + 2 + 1];
                    memcpy( hex, "0x", 2 );
                    unsigned char byte = cIt[b];
                    auto toHexChar = []( unsigned char c ) -> char { return c < 10 ? c + '0' : c - 10 + 'A'; };
                    for( size_t i = 2; i--; byte >>= 4 )
                        hex[2 + i] = toHexChar( byte & 0xF );
                    size_t nChars = 4;
                    if( b + 1 != bytesInLine )
                        memcpy( hex + 2 + 2, ", ", 2 ),
                        nChars += 2;
                    else
                        if( b + 1 < remaining )
                            hex[2 + 2] = ',',
                            ++nChars;
                    appendFn( string_view( hex, nChars ) );
                }
                cIt += bytesInLine;
                appendFn( "\n" );
            }
        };
        size_t bulkLength = 0;
        writeBulk( [&]( string_view const &sv ) { bulkLength += sv.length(); } );
        bulk.reserve( bulkLength );
        writeBulk( [&]( string_view const &sv ) { bulk += sv; } );
        ofsC << bulk;
        ofsC << "};" << endl;
    }
    catch( exception const &exc )
    {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Writing *everything* to *directly* a stream was too slow, therefore the bulk-string.
Compiling the output of a larger file can be really slow but the C-part of the output usually isn't any dependency of other files in the project.